# chance of finding two balls from a pack of 300 with a twist

Tags: probability

I need to work out a probability outcome of a scenario:

I have 300 balls, 290 different and 10 red. I have two chance of picking the red balls, with an extra bonus chance if I can't find two. so it will be either 2 chances if I get both right, or 3 if I only get 1 right in the first 2.

Comment: Please confirm that this is the problem: (1) Draw two balls.  If they are both red, stop and win.  If they are not, (2) Draw a third ball.  If you now have two red balls among the three, you win.  Otherwise, you lose.

Comment: yes, the first part is exactly the problem. The second part, if out of two draws you only have 1 ball, you will get another draw.

Comment: Are you drawing with or without replacement? That is, do you return each ball after drawing it and before drawing the next one, or are there only $298$ balls left after the first two draws?

Comment: No replacement so after the first part, there would be 298 left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add up:

- Probability of two red balls: $\dfrac{10}{300} \times \dfrac{9}{299}$
- Probability of a red then a non-red then a red: $\dfrac{10}{300} \times \dfrac{290}{299}\times \dfrac{9}{298}$
- Probability of a non-red then a red then a red: $\dfrac{290}{300} \times \dfrac{10}{299}\times \dfrac{9}{298}$

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks a lot. It was clear and very informative.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The probability of drawing a red ball on the first draw is $\frac{10}{300}=\frac1{30}$. If you succeed, the probability of drawing a second red ball is $\frac9{299}$, so the probability of winning in the first two draws is

$$\frac1{30}\cdot\frac9{299}=\frac3{2990}\;.$$

Use the same ideas to calculate the probability of drawing *red then other* and *other then red* and add these two numbers to get the probability $p$ of drawing exactly one red ball in the first two draws. At that point there will be $9$ red balls and $298$ balls altogether, and the probability of getting a red ball on the third draw will be $\frac9{298}$.

- How do you combine $p$ and $\frac9{298}$ to get the probability of winning in exactly $3$ draws?

Now just add that to the $\frac3{2990}$ probability of winning in $2$ draws.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I was going to tick your answer, but I can't as I am new to this forum.

Comment: @Septronic: You’re welcome.